# MediaRecorder Android record Wav or Mp3

Tags: android, kotlin, mp3, media, record

I am working on an android application which should record something and then send it to a server. Problem is, that I can't make the MediaRecorder that I use to output a proper MP3 file or Wav file, or I don't know, maybe a Flac.

Can you guys help me figure this out?

```
recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
                setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                setOutputFile(fileName)
                setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
```

Comment: MP3 encoding isn't directly supported, but apparently FLAC and PCM are.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats  Yet, I don't see any AudioEncoder constants for FLAC or PCM, nor do I see containers for raw-FLAC (you do have Ogg though), or WAV.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat  This question has been asked on Stack Overflow before, and there are some examples but maybe they are out-of-date.